# Simplify GTest case with repeated sequence of operations

Tags: c++, googletest

I need to test whether a sequence of operations are repeatedly invoked by MyController  with different values. Below is code related to that, how can simplify the repeated block which calls same operations with different values?

```
class MyControllerTest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    MyControllerTest() :
        m_mycontroller(m_dataBroker, m_eventBroker)
    {
    }

    testing::MockDataBroker m_dataBroker;
    testing::MockEventBroker m_eventBroker;
    MyController m_mycontroller;
};


TEST_F(MyControllerTest, ConfigureSequence)
{

    {
        InSequence dummy;
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, Prepare());
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, SetItem(Data::ID, SP::ITEM_1));
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, End());
        EXPECT_CALL(m_eventBroker, DispatchEvent(Events::ADD, _));
        m_mycontroller.Event(Events::ADDED);

        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, Prepare());
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, SetItem(Data::ID, SP::ITEM_2));
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, End());
        EXPECT_CALL(m_eventBroker, DispatchEvent(Events::ADD, _));
        m_mycontroller.Event(Events::ADDED);

        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, Prepare());
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, SetItem(Data::ID, Event::SP::ITEM_3));
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, End());
        EXPECT_CALL(m_eventBroker, DispatchEvent(Events::ADD, _));
        m_mycontroller.Event(Events::ADDED);

        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, Prepare());
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, SetItem(Data::ID, Event::SP::ITEM_4));
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, End());
        EXPECT_CALL(m_eventBroker, DispatchEvent(Events::ADD, _));
        m_mycontroller.Event(Events::ADDED);

        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, Prepare());
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, SetItem(Data::ID, Event::SP::ITEM_5));
        EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, End());
        EXPECT_CALL(m_eventBroker, DispatchEvent(Events::ADD, _));
        m_mycontroller.Event(Events::ADDED);

        m_mycontroller.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop would be sufficient

> ```
> const vector<...> items = {Event::SP::ITEM_1, Event::SP::ITEM_2, ...};
> for (const auto& item : items) {
>   EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, Prepare());
>   EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, SetItem(Data::ID, SP::ITEM_1));
>   EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, End());
>   EXPECT_CALL(m_eventBroker, DispatchEvent(Events::ADD, _));
>   m_mycontroller.Event(Events::ADDED);
> }
> m_mycontroller.start();
> ```

There's nothing special about `EXPECT_CALL` macros.  Underlying they are simply function calls on the mock object `m_dataBroker`.

Comment: I tried this but I get below error for each EXPECT_CALL                                        Mock function called more times than expected - returning directly.
   Function call : Prepare()
  Expected : to be called once
      Actual : called twice - over - saturated and active

Comment: You probably meant `EXPECT_CALL(m_dataBroker, SetItem(Data::ID, item));` in your sample. @Sirish Only put `EXPECT_CALL` statements inside the loop, that vary by `item`.